# 'GoogleUserMessagingPlatform' requires minimum platform version 12.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0

Tags: xcode, google-ads-api

I am using Xcode 14.0.1.

I added GoogleAds package with SPM. I go this error.

**Error:**
**Showing Recent Messages
The package product 'GoogleUserMessagingPlatform' requires minimum platform version 12.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0**

How can I fix this ? Minimum Deployment Target: iOS 16

[image]

[image]

[image]